# How to iterate PCA over rolling windows in R?

Tags: r, pca

I currently have a set of monthly time series data going back to 1993 for 16 variables.  I wrote the script to run PCA over the entire time period, but I need to run the calculations over rolling 12 month time periods in hindsight (so the first iteration would be for t=1 through t=12). I currently have:

```
path<- "C:/Research/Datasets"
setwd(path)
variables<- read.csv("Index (1993).csv")
prin_comp<- prcomp(variables)
prin_comp$rotation[1:16, 1]
std_dev<-prin_comp$sdev
pr_var<- stddev^2
prop_varex<- pr_var/sum(pr_var)
```

I would also like to save the loadings on the first component for all iterations and the variation of the components, but I'm getting stuck on how to do these things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are right. I didn't see that when I searched initially or before posting.